# 'Finally' statement executes twice in a recursive function [Python 3.6]p

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.6

I tried googling it but couldn't find a similar problem. I am sure it's something silly but I can't seem to get it.

I have the following code:

```
def f(a):
    try:
        4 / a
    except:
        f(2)
    else:
        print('else')
    finally:
        print("finally")
```

When I call the function with 0 as the argument: `f(0)`
It returns:

```
else
finally
finally
```

So in my understanding here is what should happen:

- 0 gets fed to the function;
- try statement can't execute it;
- except statement gets triggers, which calls the function again with a legal argument, 2.
- try statement is now okay;
- else statement prints `else`
- finally statement prints `finally`

Why does `finally` gets printed twice?

Comment: If you change the last line to `print("finally", a)` you should be able to see what is going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you invoke with `f(0)`, the `finally` block is called twice. Once for the call to `f(2)` and then again for the enclosing call to `f(0)`.

This is because `4 / 0` leads to an exception, which triggers the second call to `f` via `f(2)`.

`finally` will be invoked first for the call to `f(2)`, then for the call to `f(0)` - because `f(2)` is invoked from `f(0)`.

Comment: Why does the second `finally` gets printed _after_ the successful execution?

Comment: @4247 It's supposed to.

Comment: So `else` and `finally` are printed inside the scope of the else statement right? And the last `finally` is inside the scope of f(0)?

Comment: Because the call to f(2) completes before the call to f(0) completes as f(0) invokes f(2).

Comment: Shoot, I forgot that I enter a new scope and not just go back to the beginning.

Thanks to everyone!