# While loop vs recursion differences in try, except, finally error handling

Tags: python, recursion, error-handling, while-loop, finally

What are the differences between using a `while` loop vs recursion in `try`, `except`, `finally` error handling?

When I use a `while` loop in user input error handling:

```
while True:
    try:
        user_num = float(input("Enter a number: ")
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print("That is not a number. Error:", e)
    finally:
        print("Cycle is done.")
```

The code loops until there are no errors and each loop prints `"Cycle is done."`

When I use recursion instead of a `while` loop:

```
try:
    user_num = float(input("Enter a number: ")
except ValueError as e:
    print("That is not a number. Error:", e)
    get_num()
finally:
    print("Cycle is done.")
```

The code loops until there is no error as well and after a success it prints `"Cycle is done."` * n where n = number of cycles.

Initially I expected them both to run the same.
It seems that the `while` loop will hit the `finally` section before looping, and that the recursion method is still executing the `except` code so after a success, every call reaches `finally` in LIFO order.

I read that the recursion method will eventually raise a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` error if cycled long enough.

Are there other differences between these two methods of looping error handling?

Comment: Too many questions. Please focus on one question only. Now it is too broad. Also, asking for advantages/disadvantages is too broad too and largely subject to *opinion*, which also makes it off topic.

Comment: Recursion is almost never appropriate if you can write a loop instead. Be nice to your call stack.

Comment: This is still not a good question for this platform. You are essentially asking for differences between iteration and recursion. There are many.

Comment: See ['Finally' statement executes twice in a recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53070078/5459839)

Comment: @chepner Thank you, I will research what call stack is

Comment: @trincot Thank you, I will research iteration and recursion and their differences

Answer (score 0):

As commenters pointed out, this question could be answered with an understanding of the call stack and iteration vs recursion. I will answer my question with relevant key highlights from my research on these topics:

Iteration within a function will not add to the call stack, but recursive calls within a function will add to the call stack. Each recursion adds a stack frame to the call stack which takes memory. It's worth mentioning that Python is not designed to optimize tail recursion so as to maintain an accurate traceback. Python raises a `RecursionError` to prevent **stack overflow** when the recursion limit of 1000 is reached.
Therefore, iteration, even when having the same Big O notation, is faster and more space efficient.
Recursion can pass information to a child function call using parameters and it can pass information back to the parent calling function using return values. This makes performing operations on trees and graphs easier.

While there is no one size fits all answer, in most cases iteration is the preferable choice, especially when the goal is to repeat the code until a certain condition becomes False, like in my example.
However, recursion is useful for navigating non-linear data structures and in situations when a problem can be broken down into smaller pieces.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The `finally` codeblock only execute after the `except` has completed. But look at both codes with a dummy `returnToStart` method.

When you do a while, python run something like that:

```
try:
    user_num = float(input("Enter a number: ")
    break
except ValueError as e:
    print("That is not a number. Error:", e)
finally:
    print("Cycle is done.")
if notBreaked():
    returnToStart()
```

The second code will do this:

```
try:
    user_num = float(input("Enter a number: ")
    break
except ValueError as e:
    print("That is not a number. Error:", e)
    returnToStart()
finally:
    print("Cycle is done.")
```

So the `except` codeblock won't terminate until every call to the function was made. Thus all of the `finally` will only occure after each `get_num()` call has terminated the `except` codeblock

Answer (score -2):

Recursion is most useful when you are storing intermediate values. In a language like C where a stack frame and function call are lightweight, recursion makes sense. You have to be careful, though, because all data in the intermediate stack frames remain in memory until the recursion finally rewinds. But it sill compares well to an expanding list holding intermediate data structures allocated from the heap.

Python is different. Python's "stack frame" is really a list of function objects - one created for each function call. It's no better than a list storing intermediate values in a while loop. As such, there isn't any benefit to recursion. That's a strong statement and maybe there is *some* use, but usually not.

In your case, you don't care about the intermediate wrong answers. But in the recursion case, you keep all of them plus the exception frame until the recursion rewinds. That's not memory efficient in Python or C.